# Duplicate element being added through for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop, del

> **NOTE: I do not want to use `del`**
>
> I am trying to understand algorithms better which is why I want to avoid the built-in `del` statement.

I am populating a list of 10 randomly generated numbers.  I then am trying to remove an item from the list by index, using a `for` loop:

```
if remove_index < lst_size:
   for value in range(remove_index, lst_size-1):
        lst[value] = lst[value+1]
    lst_size -= 1
```

Everything works fine, except that the loop is adding the last item twice. Meaning, if the 8th item has the value 4, it will add a 9th item also valued 4.  I am not sure why it is doing this.  I still am able to move the value at the selected index (while moving everything up), but it adds on the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  I know there are different ways to remove an element by index.  I want to know, why this duplicate is being added to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is being added to your list. It starts out with `lst_size` elements, and, since you don't delete any, it retains the same number by the time you're done.

If, once you've copied all the items from `remove_index` onwards to the previous index in the list, you want to remove the last item, then you can do so either using `del` or [`lst.pop()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

At the risk of sounding flippant, this is a general rule: **if you want to do something, you have to do it**. Saying "I don't want to use `del`" won't alter that fact.

Merely decrementing `lst_size` will have no effect on the list - while you may be using it to store the size of your list, they are not connected, and changing one has no effect on the other.

Comment: I don't want to use del for this specific example because I want to be able to recreate this process without built-in functions.  Del does the same goal that I am trying to achieve: select the desired index, remove that index, and move all the other elements up one index. That's what I am trying to reproduce.

Comment: @Dexstrum but you're not *moving* anything... you're *copying* the values which means the two at the end are going to be the same until you remove the end item as Zero says... Nothing is being *added*... To see what's happening just add a `print(lst)` at the start of your `for`-loop and watch what happens to it...

Comment: And that's the answer I needed.  I didn't realize that I was just copying and not moving anything.